# MongoDB equivalent of WHERE IN(1,2,...)

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a list of userIDs and I want to pull out every document (naturally ordered) from a collection that are associated with one of these user IDs. Is there a MongoDB equivalent of the SQL WHERE IN?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, use Mongo's [`$in` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).